# Reduce and append in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, append, reduce

Is there a way to use reduce with numpy's append?  I want to append 3 arrays together like this:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])  
b = np.array([11,12,13])  
c = np.array([21,22,23])
#below is my real code - the above is just for this example)
np.append.reduce((a,b,c))
```

but it looks like reduce isn't implemented with append.  Thanks for any suggestions.

The output should be:

```
array([ 1,  2,  3, 11, 12, 13, 21, 22, 23])
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You're looking for either `concatenate`, `stack`, or any of the derivatives.

Comment: `np.concatenate` takes a list of arrays as input.  `np.append` is just a poorly conceived cover function that limits you to two array.  It's written Python so you can see for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

np.r_[] will do this cleanly...

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])  
b = np.array([11,12,13])  
c = np.array([21,22,23])
#below is my real code - the above is just for this example)
np.r_[a,b,c]
```

Comment: `np.r_` is another cover for `np.concatenate`, and nearly as easy to use, `np.concatenate([a, b, c])`.  In this simple case it doesn't add much.